# Compare Date in sql table to current date

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a project in which the dates in the sql table needs to be checked with current date. If the ticket goes past the current date, then the status of ticket go from Active to Expired. 
I am not good at php. This is what I came up with. I wrote this function at top of the page so that each time the page loads, it checks for the date and compares. date format is  `yyyy-mm-dd`.
 What am I doing wrong. Can anyone please help me out?

```
   $result= "SELECT date, status FROM TABLE1";

   while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){

   if(strtotime($row['date']) > strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))){

$updatequery = " UPDATE TABLE1 SET $row[status] = 'Expired' ";

}}
```

Comment: $row['date'] is correct

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: more over did you execute the query that you wrote?

Comment: I tried with the changes specified, but not able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise using the PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class it has the date diff function so you could implement like this

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
$expires = new DateTime($datefromdb);
$diff = $today->diff($expires);
if($diff < 1)
{ 
   $updatequery = " UPDATE TABLE1 SET $row[status] = 'Expired' ";
}
```

Comment: Or if your MySQL server has the correct date/time, you can just use [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) in your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$result= "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS unixdate, status FROM TABLE1";
```

and then compare

```
if ($row['unixdate']) > strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql database may be on a server whose time is different from the time on the machine where you are running the code, so I would recommend doing the check and update all on the sql server side.

(Disclaimer: I use mysql, so that's how I've written my answer. I assume you can translate to whatever sql database you use)

I would recommend using MySql's date functions, which you can see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET status='Expired' WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code working for me, just a single line of update query will updated less than of current date

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET status='expired' WHERE DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE()) < 0
```

Thank.